# AngularFire2: is it possible to retrieve a specific object from Firebase database by value?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

this is my database:
[firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jifjg.png)

I want to retrieve a dish that its 'featured' attribute is true (dish.feature = true).

is it possible? or I have to retrieve all dishes and query it on client side??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `orderByChild` and `equalTo` to achieve this using AngularFire2 [querying lists](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md):

```
db.list('/dishes', ref => ref.orderByChild('featured').equalTo(true))
```

The examples uses `db` for the injected instance of `AngularFireDatabase`, you would replace that with whatever you named your injected instance in the controller of your component executing the query.

```
@Component({ ... })
export class FooComponent {
    constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {}
}
```

**Update:**
You may receive a warning indicating an `.indexOn` needs to be added to your Firebase database rules. At the most basic level it would look like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "dishes": {
      ".indexOn": ["featured"]
    }
  }
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: thank you :D, I just needed to put ' ' around true ('true').

Comment: I would add the index as Firebase suggests as you are querying on a specific property. I added an example of added the `.indexOn` index to the Firebase database rules. Can I ask why you have true/false boolean values as a string instead of a standard boolean?

Comment: in angular I have Dish class to force types, but I am new to firebase and NoSQL. is it possibe to use types at firebase database?

Comment: Firebase database data must be valid [JSON Data Types](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp). I'd recommend making you TypeScript `Dish` class featured property be a `boolean` instead of a string, when it get's serialized it should remain a boolean rather than a string. Please mark the answer if it helped resolve your issue. Thanks!